# How to change the time format in hh:mi:ss of a w2ui time field?

Tags: jquery, w2ui

The field where I'm setting the time field is like this

`$('#stime').w2field('time',  { format: 'h24'})`

but I want seconds too, how to change the field format?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the time field supports seconds. I found two articles about it ([here](http://w2ui.com/web/docs/form/fields-date) and [here](https://davidwalsh.name/html5-input-types-alternative#date)) and there is no option for seconds:

```
$('input[type=eu-time]').w2field('time',  { format: 'h24' });
$('input[type=eu-timeA]').w2field('time', { format: 'h24', start: '8:00 am', end: '4:30 pm' });});

options = {
    format      : 'hh:mi pm',
    placeholder : '',
    keyboard    : true,
    silent      : true,
    start       : '',
    end         : ''
};
```

Comment: w2utils.formatTime($('#stime').val(), 'hh:mi:ss');

not able to solve it by this way also